# tailwind.css breakpoints in position is not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm having a problem with simple tailwind class lines.

'absolute md:static'

I want to apply for an absolute position in sm size and after md screen size, I expect to change to static again.

but I check my developer tools and it's just fixed to 'absolute'

```
  return (
    <div className="group relative flex justify-evenly items-center cursor-pointer h-full w-full overflow-visible">
      <div className={"ThisTagIsNotWorking absolute md:static"}>
        <Frame frame={frames[0]} isActivated={false} />
      </div>
      <div className={"ThisTagIsNotWorking absolute md:static"}>
        <Frame frame={frames[1]} isActivated={false} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is my test for checking my screens variable setup in tailwind and it's working as expected
(red in sm, green in md, yellow in xl)

```
<h1 className="block text-xl md:text-3xl break-keep text-red-600 md:text-green-600 xl:text-yellow-500">This is test
</h1>
```

This is my tailwind.config.cjs file and it seems to have no problem

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./*.html",
    "./src/*.tsx",
    "./src/pages/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/components/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/functions/*.tsx",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        sm: "480px",
        md: "768px",
        lg: "1024px",
        xl: "1280px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working actually. Run the snippet below and click "Full page" top right corner, then resize your browser window. It works as expected.

Copy the snippet below (without the link element on top) and change your components return element with that. You still get unexpected results? If not, can you please provide some more detailed information after your experiment.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative bg-red-200 sm:bg-green-200 md:bg-blue-200">
  <div>
    <div>dummy</div>
    <div>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute md:static top-0 right-0 z-10">this will be on top right corner if not md (blue)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it was quite a dumb mistake for me. there was a problem in my tailwind setting in my content setting route. I figure out the problem after testing your code. clearly, there is no way this simple code is not working! thanks for the help

Comment: It would be nice if you could point out that mistake, there may be someone who suffers from a similar problem.